# Where is RegisterTheViewsInTheEmbeddedViewEngine?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I'm researching how Portable Areas work with the MVC Contrib project. I've been reading a couple good blog posts and tutorials like the following:

[MVCContrib – Portable Areas](http://rob-rowe.blogspot.com/2010/06/mvccontrib-portable-areas-part-1.html)

And in them they mention a method call to perform after defining your routes in the area:

**RegisterTheViewsInTheEmbeddedViewEngine(Type t)**

I don't see that method call anywhere. Googling it did not seem to provide much. Is this method call gone? Or am I just not understanding the intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was changed some time between 2.0.50 and 2.0.90. The call no longer exists and was replaced by

```
RegisterAreaEmbeddedResources();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code for those two blog posts, it now uses the latest NuGet package for MVC 2.  In the future please feel free to leave a comment on my blog.  I would be more than happy to help resolve these types of issues.